# add external libraries jar to jmeter-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

Hello I'm using this https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin currently which the sample project works fine with a simple jmeter test.

However, I was wondering how does jars get added to the /lib folder.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
<version>1.12.174</version>
```

I need the above dependencies for my testplan in which my preprocessors uses certain imports from within it.

In JMeter its just drag and drop all jars related into the folder.

I tried adding the top code into the pom file to no avail since after running it the log file says unable to resolve import.  There seem to be plugins documentation but I thought dependencies labelled on the pom files gets built with any JMeter tests.

Any help or clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Adding jar's to the /lib directory](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)

> add any additional Java libraries to JMeter's lib/ directory by using the `<testPlanLibraries>` configuration element

> ```
> <configuration>
>                         <testPlanLibraries>
>                              <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.15.2</artifact>
> ```

In your case

```
 <artifact>com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.12.174</artifact>
```

Comment: Do I need to keep the dependency in the pom file?  Or is this downloaded/installed when you run mvn clean verify?  Also how did you come up with the artifact name, I checked mvn repository hoping there's a easy artifact name to just copy and paste but there isnt a tab for that

Comment: Never mind, got it.  Kept dependencies in the pom file and I'm guessing its [groupID][artifactID]:[versionID].  Thanks for the help